# Linked question is not linked

Tags: support, hyperlinks, linked-questions

[These](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1065927/65502) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243590/bijection-from-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-rn?lq=1) appeared on each other’s *Linked* list, **before** I made [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065927/when-was-it-realized-that-complex-numbers-cant-lie-on-a-number-line?noredirect=1#comment2168433_1065927).

As I actually had reason to link them, one question is relevant for the other and thus it could very well be that somebody linked it before me, however, I utterly fail to spot that link. In the source of the newer question (from today), the question ID does only appear for the *Linked* list. In the older question, there has been no activity (including comments) since a few months.

Comment: You mean that it was linked to that question before you did this comment?

Comment: @nicael: Yes, I do.

Answer (score 2):

Possible reason is that someone had posted an answer or comment either in the first or in the second question. Then this answer or comment got deleted. But the linked question doesn't disappear immediately; will disappear in from the sidebar tomorrow - when the cleanup for this sidebar will run (there probably was a question that the sidebar is cleaned up with the script not immediately, but I can't find it).