# A Share link does not populate the "Linked" questions when added before undeletion

Tags: support, edits, hyperlinks, deleted-answers, linked-questions

I was perplexed why a shared link to an answer [in an answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/43134/revisions) was not populating the Linked section on the right-hand side.

It turns out, it's because I edited in the link while the post was deleted then undeleted. And the fix was to remove the link, save, readd it.

Is this as designed, or a bug?
It is my understanding that links in deleted answers (and comments<sup>?</sup>) still populate the Linked section, so I'm guessing it's not related to the post being deleted. Perhaps the script needs to run again after undeletion?

Update: I tested in a now-deleted answer to *this* question, but I can't reproduce. My guess is the script failed to run for some reason where I encountered it.

---

**After undeletion:**

> [image: before]

**After removing link and readding:**

> [image: after]

**What happened:**

> [image: timeline]

Note: the suggested edit is unrelated to the link to the answer that wasn't showing:

> [image: different links]

Comment: Exact duplicate, but old enough to bump: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294605/282094 --- Examples disproving: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/90393/why-report-pressure-setting-in-use-qnh-qfe-on-first-contact [10K]  https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3998/homework-questions-has-something-changed-perhaps-network-wide Cross-site:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295965/question-in-linked-sidebar-is-not-referenced-anywhere-in-this-question-or-its?rq=1

Comment: @Rob: I figured it out and now pivoted the question.

Comment: Non-authoritative answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245098/282094 and duplicate (probably without an answer that explains this case): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287417/282094  and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315218/282094